# Backstage (Spotify): New variables are not being recognized on app-config.yaml file

Tags: backstage

I'm trying to setup differents app-config files for differents environments on backstage, like app-config.development.yaml and app-config.production.yaml. This is working, when I override a variable on one of these files, its being updated correctly.

But when I add new variables, It's not showing anywhere. I'm getting the values on the plugin using useApi and configApiRef from '@backstage/core-plugin-api' but its showing, even when i run the command: backstage-cli config:print --frontend --config app-config.yaml the new variable is being displayed on the output

I need to update the file and get the values on the frontend plugin. Is there any command that i have to run every time I update the app-config?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you might be doing this already but I'll take a stab. Are you extending an existing community plugin or creating a new one?

When you add a new variable and expect it to show up on the frontend when asking for the config, you need to set it's visibility to 'frontend' in the plugins `config.d.ts` file. By default the visibility is 'backend'.

Like

```js
export interface Config {
  myPlugin: {
    /**
     * @visibility frontend
     */
    baseUrl: string;
  };
}
```

You can read about visibility [in the Backstage docs](https://backstage.io/docs/conf/defining#schema-collection-and-definition).